# Disable submit button if none selected using #states

Tags: 7, javascript

The code

```
     $form['type'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select', 
      '#title' => t('Type of new field'),
      '#options' => $field_type_options,
      '#empty_option' => t('- Select a field type -'),
      // '#empty_value' => 0,
      '#description' => t('Type of data to store.'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['save'] = array (
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => t ('Save field'),
     '#states' => array(
       'disabled' => array(
         ':input[name="type"]' => array('value' => 0),
         // Tried value = NULL, value = FALSE - no luck
)),
```

);

The goal is to disable submit button if none selected from drop-down list. Which "value" should I provide? Tried "0", "FALSE", "NULL"

Comment: i think you can't catch the select's changed event, so you need to write some custom javascript attachted via a [drupal behavoir](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#drupal_behaviors) or a module hoooking [AJAX Form](http://drupal.org/node/752056)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "#empty_option" will not give a value, which is needed for #states, a workaround is to add the default as an actual option:

```
$field_type_options = array( 0 => '- Select a field type -');

$form['type'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Type of new field'),
  '#options' => $field_type_options,
  '#description' => t('Type of data to store.'),
  '#default_value' => isset( $form_state['values']['type'] ) ?  $form_state['values']['type'] : 0,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  $form['save'] = array (
   '#type' => 'submit',
   '#value' => t ('Save field'),
   '#states' => array(
     'disabled' => array(
       ':input[name="type"]' => array('value' => 0),
      )
    )
  );
```

This allows #states to test the value and disable the item

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this (no #empty_option workaround) is to check for the empty string ('') value.

```
'#states' => array(
  'disabled' => array(
    ':input[name="type"]' => array('value' => ''),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the #empty_value at the same time.

empty_option is the text
empty_value is the value

```
 $form['type'] = array(        
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Type of new field'),
'#options' => $field_type_options,
'#empty_option' => t('- Select a field type -'),
'#empty_value' => 'blank',
'#description' => t('Type of data to store.'),
'#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Hope it works for you